# Is there any way to gain Fate without spending money?

Tags: fallen-london

I know Fate is generally the premium currency in the game Fallen London, but is there any way to earn it without spending real world money on it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will generally get a small amount (1-3 Fate) from completing major storylines, such as An Agent of the Cheesemonger or the University storylines, and some of the Dream storylines. It's not the most reliable way of earning it however, as usually these storylines are one-off event chains.

This is by design, of course - Fate/Nex is the main source of income for Failbetter.

Comment: You also get a handful of Fate (about 7) for telling the game developers your age and gender; there are a couple of Opportunity cards that come up.